# Help deciphering this fdisk output

Tags: partitioning

**additional info::**  It was asked if these three drives were in a RAID config, and they are.  I know almost nothing about RAID, but I know this machine has a RAID controller.

I was given a Dell Poweredge server by a friend.  I installed an SSD and on that, installed Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS.  The server also has (3) Cheetah SAS drives installed, all of which have data.  I'm trying to more or less scrub these drives, then create a single EXT4 partition on each of them which I'll use as HTPC media storage.  As a semi-newbie to Linux, I'm trying to find whichever way I need to first visualize these three drives so I can figure out where to go from there.  I've issued "fdisk -l" and the following is the output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd8ea6a9e

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 234440703 234438656 111.8G 83 Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 557.8 GiB, 598879502336 bytes, 1169686528 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000080

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1               63       2047       1985 992.5K 42 SFS
/dev/sdb2  *          2048     206847     204800   100M 42 SFS
/dev/sdb3           206848 1169682431 1169475584 557.7G 42 SFS
/dev/sdb4       1169682432 1169684479       2048     1M 42 SFS
```

I *would* say I recognize /dev/sda as my 120GB SSD which runs the OS, but then I see /dev/sda1, and after that, in the list of /dev/sdb's, I just don't recognize three separate 600GB storage drives.

Can you help me break down the output of this command, or give me a better command which might output a cleaner presentation?

Thanks!

Comment: You see one drive with 120 GB and one drive with 600 GB. That's all. could it be that there is some kind of RAID setup, and it is not recognized by Ubuntu? Or are two 600 GB drives not recognized by the computer's BIOS? Or something else?

Comment: The one recognized 600GB drive is partitioned with an MBR partition table, not GPT, FYI. What controller runs those three SAS drives? Please provide more information by clicking [edit] and adding that info.

Comment: Maybe you can get additional help with SAS and RAID at the [Ubuntu Forum for servers](https://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=339).